# Is Google's Documentation Correct on How Cross-Domain Tracking Works?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, conversion-tracking

Researching options for Universal Analytics to setup cross-domain ecommerce tracking. Project has 3 existing separate Google Analytics Accounts for 3 domains, not setup for cross-domain tracking currently. Setting up Universal Analytics to track conversions across those multiple domains from original traffic course to cart conversion.

I have done this before for other funnels using separate Property IDs for each domain, so was surprised to read this in the Google Docs for Universal Cross-Domain tracking:

> "Both domains need to use the same GA property in order for cross-domain tracking to work correctly. If the sites use different properties, no session information will be shared and **cross-domain tracking will not work**." [my emphasis]

When you autolink, you pass the _ga parameter, and it seems like this works across multiple accounts (or across multiple properties) to connect (for instance) PPC campaigns > domain 1 to eventual revenue > domain 2  (or 3, etc.).

So, what is being said here? Is it just plain wrong, or something that I am missing about sessions?  For multiple domains, is your experience implementing this that a rollup property is required? Or preferable in some way?

Comment: That an property can re-use a client id set by another property does not mean it shares session information, which with UA is evaluated server-side per property).  For example even if a property uses the _ga parameter it will have no idea which was the original source for that visits, or how many pages the user viewed at that other domain. As far as cross domain sessions are concerned the shared client id is necessary, but not sufficient - that might be what you are missing about session.

Comment: Hi Eike - when you pass the _ga parameter, in reports, we can see which original AdWords ad click that was sent to Domain 1, ended up converting to a sale on Domain 2. Isn't that one definition of Cross Domain Tracking working?